# SQL Split string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I am Using SQL Server 2008. i have a Table of "Course", having one column with name of "Courses" . I insert "Courses" in table "Course" and get a string For example "Math English Physics".

How do I split a string so I can access each course? How can I split the string by a space and access the item at index 1 which should return "English"?

Comment: get the result first and split next

Comment: Is this a legacy system? Can you instead normalize your database? Apparently you have a 1:n relationship between something and course, if possible you should design the db accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Create a User Defined Function (UDF) as below:

```
 Declare @course varchar(200) = 'Math English Physics'
Declare @individual varchar(20) = null

WHILE LEN(@course) > 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('% %',@course) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = SUBSTRING(@course, 0, PATINDEX('% %',@course))
        SELECT @individual

        SET @course = SUBSTRING(@course, LEN(@individual + ' ') + 1,
                                                     LEN(@course))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = @course
        SET @course = NULL
        SELECT @individual
    END
END
```

i hope this may solve your problem.

BUt i believe you should restructure your database and normalize it.

Comment: making all that varchar manipulating is not good for performance. Selecting them 1 by 1 is also a terrible idea. You can use eather recursive sql or xml split much more effective

Comment: ya i agree with you @t-clausen.dk

Comment: What's with the `@products`? Customize the code a little ..